# function representation of power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, factorial, differential

What is the function representation of this power series?

[Summation from n=0 to infinity of [($x^n)(n+1)!/n!$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNUSI.png)

The solution is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^-2}$ but how???

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^n)/n! = e^x$, but I don't know how to get to the solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}x^n=\frac{(n+1)n!}{n!}x^n=(n+1)x^n$$ So, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n +\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} +\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=$$ $$x \frac d {dx}\Big( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\Big)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

I am sure that you cn take it from here.

Comment: how did you get an extra n! to cancel out the original n! in the denominator?

Comment: Remember that $k!=k\times (k-1)!=k\times (k-1)\times (k-2)!$

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more, i'm not so sure what to do with the differentiate summation

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ ?

Comment: lol i got it , thanks

Comment: Good ! You are welcome !